# Nginx root/location combination

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, configuration

I've this configuration:

```
server {
    server_name my.project.com;
    index index.php;
    root /project/api/v1.0;

    location /api/v1.0/ {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

I'm using Slim Framework and my front controller is inside /project/api/v1.0/index.php. Why this is not working? I'm having timeout and no response visiting https://my.project.com/api/v1.0/ .

Comment: You have no [listen directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) in your configuration, so your server is not listening on any port. Add something like `listen 80 default_server;` and connect through HTTP (not HTTPS). After you can configure a [HTTPS server](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html).

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz it will be listening on port 80 as that is the default.

Comment: You will get a timeout using `https` because you have not configured an `https` server. Your server is accepting connections for `http` only. Your `root` and `location` directives are confusing as they both include `/api/v1.0/`. If you want to use `/api/v1.0/` in the URI, you should probably remove it from the `root` statement and use `/api/v1.0/index.php` at the end of the `try_files` statement.